# How can I make a multi item bootstrap 4 carousel work on IE 11?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I tried several solutions for a multi item carousel until I found this one

https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-custom-carousel-94a537364fde

The problem is that this carousel doesn't work on IE 11 correctly, the animations just don't work as they should.

Another problem that I can't use a background color in the container of the carousel because this affect the slide effect, so the only alternative I found is to color the body background.

Any one who knows how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Here is my test

https://www.codeply.com/go/aN1JSTlw7x